# Slow loading in react native video 5.2.0 (0.69 RN), What should I do?

Tags: react-native, performance, video-player, react-native-video

I am new to React native Apps, And developed a basic news app which contains video posts, Everything was fine but videos are loading very slow.

Video will be uploaded from app to the backend server, and posts will be displayed in flat list and server is very fast but still having same low speed loading.

using Backend as Laravel, tried so many trick but still same issue,
How can I improve video loading speed? Any help will make save my time, Its is more than a month but still no solution,

Is these any better option to display video post in flat list?
How can I improve slow video loading?

Comment: Have you tried changing the video codec or resolution to make the video files smaller?

Comment: Yes, I tried  different resolutions, but still facing same issue as before, could  you please  provide  any example to solve this issue.

Comment: You tried different resolutions and the loading time was exactly the same? What was the difference in file size?

Comment: At first file size is 40 MB, and then i used 7 mb file but same loading time, I used video compressor to compress the file, and 40 mb file becomes  7 mb before upload, and then that compressed file was uploaded to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, seriously problem is my shared server, my server is fast and data is loading very fast, but when it comes to videos and images,speed is bit slow... so I shifted my storage to AWS s3 and with AWS CLOUD FRONT And, that was the perfect solution for me.